# Comparison between pointer and integer

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Why doesn't this work?

```
for (int *i = 0; i < (int)[[[data objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] valueForKey:@"pictures"] count]; i++) {

    NSLog(@"another picture to add");

}
```

It gives me a warning in the first line, saying "Comparison between pointer and integer". I don't really know how to solve this, the code is executing and it doesn't crash but nothing is being logged to the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're declaring `i` as a pointer: `int *i = 0`. Should be `int i = 0`.

Answer (score 2):

`i` is a pointer to an integer (because of the `*`). Probably not what you want. Try

```
for (int i = 0; i <     // etc ....
```

Answer (score 2):

You've declared `i` as `int *` rather than `int`. Why?

Answer (score 2):

why are you using `int *i`, i guess u should use just `int i`. 
try it 
good luck

Answer (score 2):

You have declared int *i that means i is going to hold address of some variable and with

```
i < (int)[[[data objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]
```

statement you are trying to compare with the value which is also typecast to int :) and this is reason it is giving warning.. use just int i.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < (int)[[[arRef objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] valueForKey:@"pictures"] count]; i++) {

    NSLog(@"another picture to add");

}
```